# Simple test of image containing text in it against pre-defined template

Tags: c#, image, ocr

I have a small image of a text in it, a screenshot from a small area in a console application. I need a simplest possible test to tell if it matches a pre-defined pattern. In other words, if text is exactly some specific word, let's say, "root".

Font is fixed, no rotations, but it should be robust to small offsets.

So, my *template/pattern* image is fixed: [image: This image is fixed]

And my *test* image can be this: [image: Test image that should yield positive result]

In case of negative result, I don't need to extract text from it or anything. So, I'm looking for the simplest test possible.

I tried to calculate number of white pixels in the image, but that's unreliable.

Comment: I think you are better off relying on OCR techniques.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/16268/whats-the-best-simplest-ocr-solution for a list of OCR suggestions.

Comment: You can also use imageMagicks `compare` functionality for this (with the `---subimage-search` flag) to perform template matching, if you prefer that route. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php

Comment: Any sort of simple image profile vector/statistics that could do the trick? Doesn't OCR seem to be a bit too much for this simple case?